# Getting text from TextView in UI test in XCTest

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-ui-automation, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying XCode for iOS UI testing. My test application has UITextView element with accessibility identifire `displayTextView`.

I tried simple test that taps this element, types some text it and then check the result the following way:

```
XCUIElement *textView = app.textViews[@"displayTextView"];
[textView tap];
[textView typeText:@"9.9"];
```

It works. But then I can't get the typed text from the text view. I tried to do it by the following:

```
XCTAssertEqual([textView.accessibilityValue isEqualToString:@"9.9"]);
```

But it seems it is incorrect, because textView.accessibilityValue is null.
What method would be appropriate to get the typed text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the answer. The correct way is:

```
XCTAssert([textView.value isEqualToString:@"9.9"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

or `let text = textView.value as! String`

Comment: complete answer: `XCTAssertEqual("9.9", textView.value as? String)`

Answer (score -2):

I used:

```swift
let expectedValue = "Hello World!"
XCTAssert(app.staticTexts[expectedValue].isHittable)
```

Using this approach, we look for labels displaying `expectedValue`, and verify if it is visible...

Comment: No way! XCTest will never find the textview's text as staticText.